# Installation problems with Mongo on Nitrous.io container

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, nitrousio

I created an Ubuntu container on Nitrous.io so that I can develop on my chromebook without the chromebook's limitation. I am having trouble using mongodb. I followed these steps to install it:

```
~ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

~ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list

~ sudo apt-get update

~ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

~ sudo service mongod start
```

I can't connect to mongo through the mongo shell. I get this error message:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6
connecting to: test
2015-10-02T21:13:56.629+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-10-02T21:13:56.630+0000 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

I have tried deleting the lock file and creating a 'data' directory and then setting the dbpath to that directory:

```
~ sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

~ sudo service mongodb restart
```

and

```
~ mkdir data

~ cd data

~ mongod --dbpath .
```

The Ubuntu container is 64 bit 14.04 I believe Nitrous uses Docker containers if that makes a difference. I don't think I have direct root access, but I have sudo access which doesn't require a password. More generally, has anyone else had a lot of problems installing Mongo? I can never seem to get it to just install smoothly.

Comment: What output do you get when you do a `cat /var/log/mongodb/mongo.d`

Comment: Cat: /var/log/mongodb/mongo.d: no such file or directory

Comment: Why not just use the meteor stack? That comes with mongo preinstalled.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I just gave that a try, typed mongo into the terminal and it says command not found. I also tried a mongo --version and I get a command not found. I can't change the whole project over to the meteor stack at this point so I was hoping to just mooch off the mongo install. I'm not too familiar with meteor. Is the mongo install somehow only accessible through meteor?

Comment: Tell me how it went :)

Comment: Mind sharing the container with me, I might be able to help. I'm `gamesbrainiac@gmail.com` over there.

Comment: i've shared the container. so far i've installed mongo, express and and nvm / node came with the container. I installed mongo from the ubuntu repository using the mongo manual instructions and i've also attempted installing with auto parts. the log file says no room for journaling and is not waiting for connections. I have tried to enable small files but that hasn't changed anything.

Comment: It is a Node container, not a Meteor container as you suggested previously, but I tried that as well.